# How to store Model loaded by ColladaLoader in Three.js?

Tags: three.js

Since the Three.js migration (r68 -> r69) the ColladaLoader returns a Scene instead of an Object3D. How can I get the loaded Object3D now? I want store the loaded Object in a var to use it everytime.

```
                var newpos = Cube.position;
                var oLoader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
                oLoader.load('models/logo.dae', 
                    function(collada) 
                    {
                      var object = collada.scene;
                      var skin = collada.skins[0];
                      object.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
                      object.rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;
                      object.position.x = newpos.x;
                      object.position.y = newpos.y+1.85;
                      object.position.z = newpos.z;
                      object.scale.set(0.75, 0.75, 0.75);
                      object.updateMatrix();
                      scene.add(object);
                    },
                    function ( xhr ) {
                //      console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );
                    }
                );
```

Comment: In three.js r.70, this was reverted. See https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/28434270e949f36b67b2c46f9d1e667b36b562ce and https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5754.

Comment: Ah, didn't noticed this change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ColladaLoader returns a scene because the loaded Model is'nt created as a 3DObject. The ColladaLoader creates a new scene added to your scene including the loaded .dae-Model. (Now it returns a group) That's because not every Model is just one Object. Check the childs of the dae.scene that you loaded, it helps a lot.